# How to create a custom dropdown which shows the selected item by an icon?

Tags: flutter, dart

Example of a custom dropdown i created but fail to show the selected dropdownmenuitem by  icon.Here if i set isSelected to true all the dropdown Items show the icon but i want only the selected dropdown item to show the icon.The icon im using is Icons.verified_rounded.

Is there a way this can be achieved?
Sample code of custom widget below.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width ,
      height: height ,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: margin ?? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      padding: padding ?? EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: backGroundColor ?? Colors.white,
          border: border ?? Border.all(color: gray),
          borderRadius: borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
          icon: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 1,
              child: endWidget ??
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null)),
          iconSize: 18,
          hint: Text(
            selectedValue ?? 'Select',
            style: style ??
                TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: gray),
          ),
          isExpanded: true,
          underline: const SizedBox(),
          onChanged: (String newValue) => onChange(newValue),
          items: children.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(value),
                  Spacer(),
                  (isSelected) ? Icon(Icons.verified_rounded) : SizedBox()
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `index` variable to check which item is selected.

```
// Index variable which stores which item is selected
int index = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
      ...
      child: DropdownButton(
         ...
         items: children.asMap().entries.map((String v) {
           return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
             // v.value gives the value at that index
              value: v.value,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(value),
                  Spacer(),
                  // v.key will give the index 
                  // This checks if index is at that value or not
                  (index == v.key) ? Icon(Icons.verified_rounded) : SizedBox()
                ],
              ),
            );
         }).toList(),
      ),
   );
}
```

If you have any doubt comment it.